# NuoDB Stored Procedure call with Multilevel Parameters from Java

Tags: java, stored-procedures, nuodb

Has anyone tried to call NuoDB Stored Procedure with Multilevel List Parameters from Java?

Any working example how to do it? Please share if anyone achieved this.

Answer (score 0):

I am unclear what specifically you mean by "multilevel List parameter".

I can think of:

- a table-value - NuoDB supports this; both for input params (as a ResultSet) and as output;

  - Eg: CREATE PROCEDURE prc_rs_input (IN tmphockey (number INTEGER, name STRING) )
    See: http://doc.nuodb.com/Latest/Default.htm#SQL-Procedural-Result-Set-As-Input.htm

    - However, I don't think JDBC has support for a ResultSet parameter; I can confirm if that is what you are after.
- multiple ResultSets from an sproc - NuoDB sprocs support this;

  - and I believe this works with the JDBC multiple Results API;
    See: http://doc.nuodb.com/Latest/Default.htm#SQL-Procedural-Returning-Multiple-Result-Sets.htm
- a temporary table - NuoDB supports this;
- some form of hierarchical structure such as XML (not XML text) - NuoDB does not support hierarchical structures such as XML.

Comment: Hi Nik, Thanks for the reply. I meant List of List<String> or Array of String Array as "Multilevel List". This is only for Input. Our Output is String[] or List<String>. Input is our challange.